# (php) echo in echo include not work

Tags: php

I have a file in **new_pm.php** contains code like this:

```
<?php include 'box_right.php';?>
```

then, in the **box_right.php** contains code like this:

```
<?php
echo "<div class="box_right">
        <a href="list_pm.php">Pesan(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?>)</a> - <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> (<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>)
    </div>";
?>
```

However, a warning like this:

*Parse error: syntax error ....*

How do I resolve this?

edit:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='box_right'>
        <a href='list_pm.php'>Pesan(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?>)</a> - <a href='profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>'><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> (<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>)
    </div>";
?>
```

Comment: you're already in PHP.

Comment: use concatenation operator instead of echo inside echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your PHP block with this code:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="box_right">
        <a href="list_pm.php">Pesan(' . $nb_new_pm . ')</a> - <a href="profile.php?id=' . $_SESSION['userid'] .'">' . htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</a> (<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>)
    </div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me

Comment: am glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

Either escape the double quotes within the string, or change the quotes around the string to single quotes.

Also remove the second set of php tags.